# Which Project Type to select in InstallShield : Basic MSI or C#.Net Wizard for WPF application?

Tags: wpf, installation, installshield

I have created one WPF application...
Now, in installshield, i want to make installation package for the same, so which project type i should select?

---

Actualy, now i have used basic MSI project....

but m still struggling with another problem....

i have created setup in English and German languages.... and i want to install .Net framework language pack according to the language selected by user....

Can any1 help me out...??

Answer (score 0):

The C# wizard adds the InstallShield project to your visual studio solution.  Personally I never put my application code and installer code in the same solution so I would just choose the Basic MSI project type.

Comment: @christopher Please have a look at my problem its really important and i need help. [Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861026/include-all-dll-files-as-part-of-wpf-app-installation-using-installshield-and-lo)